# Port forwarding broken after Windows Update

Tags: port-forwarding

I'm not exactly sure what truly caused it but it definitely happened after I restarted my machine after applying updates to it. I used to be able to remote desktop connect to my computer by using my assigned IP from my ISP and using port forwarding on my router to forward to the right computer. In addition I have also some other ports I forward to this machine that also stopped working as well.

Does anyone have any ideas of what I can check to see what I can do to get this working again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what I did.  But it definitely had to do with the modem settings, or perhaps just needed a reboot.  I don't think I had to truly change anything.  Just a weird issue.

Answer (score 0):

Double check that firewall software isn't blocking the services.  Also check you still have the same statically set IP address that the port forwards are pointing to.

Comment: What is strange is I'm still able to access the ports from within the local network.  It's only when I try to access it from outside the network.

Comment: I have completely disabled Windows Firewall and I have no other firewalls installed.